# Redis sort ignoring whitespaces

Tags: sorting, redis

Trying to do sorting in redis with the following command:

```
sort ids by messages|*->ss ASC LIMIT 0 10 GET messages|*->ss ALPHA
```

messages|.ss is string value
output:

```
1 that of
a community in
add ensuring so      #this should be at the end before b...
against entitled and #this should be at the end before b...
a give and
a he can
a objective world
a of like
a to I
birthday moment daily
```

As you can see whitespaces are ignored. I'm expecting those lines to be at the end before "birthday moment daily"

```
add ensuring so
against entitled and
```

Tried to set LC_ALL=C and LC_COLLATE=C environment variables, didn't help.

redis 3.0.0

CentOS 6.5